# Unsung Heroes of RC.SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is not realy a meta question and I wouldn't mind if it get deleted in a few days. I just have the urge to ventilate this again:

## Thanks to all the editors easing the way I mangle the English language.

It may not look like it, but I realy apreciate all the help that is given.

Members like [LangLangC](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/6802/langlangc), [Manassehkatz](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4921/manassehkatz) or [Wilson](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/576/wilson) (**many other as well**) spend considerable time to work their way word by word thru my letter piles, making them often readable in the first place.

I wish there was a way to reflect this with the reputation score, as some of the people investing much efford into editing stay unsung heroes for their engagement. Requests for incooperation into the score is geting rejected every time someone asks (tried it a year ago as well) :(

Anyway, **thank you to all helping here**

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Yes there's the occasional incorrect word but you clearly know what you're talking about.  Just a few minutes ago I decided, out of respect, against editing one of your posts to correct an almost-right-but-not-quite word.  Thanks for all your contributions!

Comment: You are welcome! And don't sweat the reputation; it's awarded to you since you bring a lot of excellent content to this site.

Comment: @Wilson None the less, it takes more than writing up some old time momory to make a successful and apealing entry - not to mention the site as whole.